# Java Non-negative multiple linear regression library

Tags: linear-regression, java

I am working on a Java project, and I have to compute a multiple linear regression, but I want the gotten parameters to be non-negative. Is there an existing commercial-friendly-licensed library to do such a thing? I've been looking for Non-Negative Least Squares libs, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I could not find any pure java library so I built it myself from the article of [1], wich can be found in [2] and [3]. I give the algorithm:

P, R are the active and the passive sets. t() is transpose

The problem is to solve Ax = b under the condition x>0

```
P=null
R = {1,2,...,m}
x = 0
w = t(A)*(b-A*x)
while R<>null and max{wi|i in R}>0 do:
    j = argmax{wi|i in R}
    P = P U {j}
    R = R\{j}
    s[P] = invert[t(A[P])A[P]]t(A[P])b
    while sp<=0 do:
        a = -min{xi/(di-xi)|i in P and di<0}
        x = x + a*s -x
        update(P)
        update(R)
        sP = invert[t(A[P])A[P]]t(A[P])b
        sR = 0
    x = s
    w = t(A)*(b-A*x)
return x
```

For the other definitions, I strongly advise to read the papers [2] and [3], which are online (see below for the links ;) )

[1] Lawson, C. L., & Hanson, R. J. (1974). Solving least squares problems (Vol. 161). Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice-hall.
[2] Rasmus Bro et Sijmen De Jong : A fast non-negativity-constrained least squares
algorithm. Journal of chemometrics, 11(5) :393–401, 1997. http://www.researchgate.net/publication/230554373_A_fast_non-negativity-constrained_least_squares_algorithm/file/79e41501a40da0224e.pdf
[3] Donghui Chen et Robert J Plemmons : Nonnegativity constraints in numerical analysis. In Symposium on the Birth of Numerical Analysis, pages 109–140, 2009. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.9203&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache Commons Math, making your constraints an additional cost to the objective function.  See section 14.4 here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/leastsquares.html

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)? It's Java and under GNU General Public License. It's mainly a GUI-Tool for experiments, but you can use it as a library too. It should have implementations of  linear regressions.

Comment: Thank you for answer but Weka does not seem to have the features I need. I have not found non-negative linear regression, nor multiple linear regression. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: not sure what "logistic" means, but what about http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/supervisedAttributeScaling/weka/classifiers/functions/NonNegativeLogisticRegression.html?

Comment: Thank you much. Logistic regression is different from linear regression, quite far actually. It is actually a binary predictor.

Answer (score 1):

As [George Foreman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069400/george-forman) pointed out you can use apache commons math. 
In particular there is the object **OLSMultipleLinearRegression** which provides tha methods for performing multiple regression analysis.

Here is some code on how to do it.

OLSMultipleLinearRegression ols = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();

double[] data = new double[75];

int numberOfObservations = 25;

int numberOfIndependentVariables = 3;

```
    try {
        ols.newSampleData(data, numberOfObservations, numberOfIndependentVariables);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

And here is the whole github project from where you can download a working example on how to use multiple regression in Java : https://github.com/tekrar/MultRegressionInJava